# jwt-go: key is invalid error with RS256 generated from mkjwk.org

Tags: go, jwt, jwk

I am using the https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go library like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
)

var jwtKey = []byte(`
{
    "p": "7KKWYO2Mdmjm1eIAjpMOtcjfYlslYVthVVecxJyq4sr9v9HUxmN-VWCJaDBBb9iTm8zCoRNauiNhgk4vViK56T6Ooo93GHiHsVtpIB9MgL1NZuHoHZtQL6iq1faRp2A5Xca8TrcxQ4k8snHpndjjnrQj1XtvEESzL23lu-S-280",
    "kty": "RSA",
    "q": "rr-eu9klZeYH8D3DZ6OmBlVFCi7dFHx9uepcrHOlxeZJBg9y5882X2Uw_z4OfIBUHNux0yKXkkHhehiM7gSxb7m75ap54LWG35q9JGU2qI_DvlvEgMObqz-YER4satI7LPbIMISHUyqkcN86SA9olVLNK3kDEsukx_LcnKs7bxc",
    "d": "QxO-9QTZtZ7oHIifMBlFInIstI8CYdVobLhbl_OFA8vTygX_ZG5-i-REYaYUJyx_WwHYYI8HsWmbZsrf2rc7Y76E2OCRGuyEK4lA-YeP2FYX09hwuIvYTXc_KErenp6rbo8W0EU49FIYdTk7Szlx9RF-gatOZXVJqM-nHnh3sHm3facnBba94_2L91eIKezJ1VeuWwxpR2sRZzbQdrOI_sPYurIdLZGeTGYF7kKIcgyMydxchRpiKKapXm--sPewNlzw7NMMU5PLXKIc9YA8rKU2G1OgRxVOrleeKiK4zLZY46ry60Lu2zzwLTQL6uyiGIG0f9hp0TYZY8qedShS-Q",
    "e": "AQAB",
    "use": "sig",
    "kid": "sdfasda",
    "qi": "dsVrwVQnK9WigTluBTq5DTHkbRoeKhp67y8i4LaE5hst3vSd_VrFB1aYhJuHD-c0B8cBt-QQbqN7sUit7OiXS8u7iIoIuTTsS0vBexpJpPMv-GGOQnBrc0pyFvLX_HjJqZRBH4ZsBmI4Zfn6E0NCjEuSPfksxYYz4Df62T9jrgM",
    "dp": "tE7bCPZYziz2n0i7JehWEBwEYrySyhFIJDBDCulZqMAGA_COEbDkJYgOi24hnmjHaLLoJrZJroWhGhobJaYGRPze0G1C0UmeE31UqB5RO9OCs_80z8J1oisCKVDdAU1nyNXSzKP4DL74mfwEh7spDdezakrIgPvoER7LK5WL_I0",
    "alg": "RS256",
    "dq": "K79vJsoDEdKX1C4yOEUA8H7ybM00rcdI1n10u_ur2bKAP5Moih4XF6TGsm-_wq2B4UOi7h-v4H67ywxQY9oq7bSK9MFMB9SKMnqTtYPdPi_XqlVhCXdvBl1CXa63IfsFs4kIrxTOqCR5zIQmHBo3bYKwOJzwBwmSdDg5wMMhevs",
    "n": "oYeiPhASwtqH9RhjfaEPxaw3j-iWIwwDvrnIaPgUT9A175fJ10mKWJ4butQPXQJKcGHcOJ88pftcXe_KBW2sGj5VYyFiPzVpU3C5TFITbtseTEo0VCNDisow2no4BVFDj2h95EA9WGwbktyqE0C4Dc2-_iBXJlQuOY_RBlOlEOxRzxEBxMOiolN9X2CfqJ6DpFKR3wr58pbaYGgdzTL6dRA_aJ7P-V7x8_IYFGYqwYjThIXvWOGwWaSR6Q4iA8pwuNOPegJeFxPom0u67vMZ65EU_c0WH4kv8ucqQq7g_GgL2IDmWaRYykiy6OE8G-hHAGIW898IoyHpkW3K5bKiaw"
}
`)

type Claims struct {
    Username string `json:"username"`
    jwt.StandardClaims
}

func main() {
    expirationTime := time.Now().Add(5 * time.Minute)

    claims := &Claims{
        Username: "prakhar",
        StandardClaims: jwt.StandardClaims{
            // In JWT, the expiry time is expressed as unix milliseconds
            ExpiresAt: expirationTime.Unix(),
        },
    }

    // Declare the token with the algorithm used for signing, and the claims
    token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodRS256, claims)
    // Create the JWT string
    tokenString, err := token.SignedString(jwtKey)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(tokenString)

    tkn, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(tokenString, claims, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        return jwtKey, nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        if err == jwt.ErrSignatureInvalid {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    if !tkn.Valid {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // Finally, return the welcome message to the user, along with their
    // username given in the token
    fmt.Printf("Welcome %s!", claims.Username)
}
```

And it's not able to use the key. It fails saying key is invalid. I generated the key on mkjwk.org.

Comment: first: the package jwt-go is no longer maintained (see [notice](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go) on their Github page), so better don't use it anymore. Second: the key you're using there is a JSON Web Key (JWK). You can`'t just cast it to byte like that and use it directly. You would need a function to import a JWK. That package dosen't offer that functionatily.

Comment: So, I am a little confused. So, does the rsa.PrivateKey parsed by jwx package can be used in jwt-go package?

Comment: my solution in the linked Q/A does not use jwt-go, but the OP of the question mentioned that they used the imported key with jwt-go, so it might work, but I didn't test that.